# RxJava: How to subscribe to 2 observables in order and merge their result?

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, rx-java3

To set the stage, I have 2 network calls, the 2nd one depends on the result of the 1st.

```
fun netCall1(): Observable<Data1>{...}

fun netCall2(data: Data1): Observable<Data2>{...}
```

How do I create a stream that subscribes to netCall1(), uses the result to subscribe to netCall2(), then merges the results of both calls and return that?

```
net1: --1--2----------3-------- 
net2: -----------a-b--c--------
res : -----------P(1,a)--P(2,b)-P(3,c)---------
(network calls may retry up to 3 times, P means Pair<Data1,Data2>)
```

This is my attempt, but I'm unsure how to merge the results together.

```
fun myAttempt(): Observable<Pair<Data1, Data2>>{
  Observable.just()
    .flatMap{ netCall1() }
    .flatMap{ data1 -> netCall2(data1) }
    // unsure how to proceed...
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a detailed description of how the data should be "merged". Provide a marble diagram if possible to show when the observables generate the data objects and how you want to combine them.

Comment: Which value from one observable is "merged" or combined with what value from the other observable. Please use different values in the marble diagram. Also explain and/or show an example how the `Pair` instance should be build when `net2` is producing new values when the `net1` observable is not producing any new values. It is unclear how the value from `net1` have an affect on the subscriptions and/or values from `net2`. It is unclear if a new observable for `net2` is returned/used or how they depends on each other. If necessary, show the source code of the `net1` and `net2` observables.

Comment: You might want to look into the `zip()` operator to build the `Pair` instance you want.

Comment: Recommended reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#dependent-sub-flows

Comment: @Progman I need to feed the response of the 1st call to the 2nd one as they are dependent, so I don't think I can use zip().

Comment: @akarnokd the nested flatMap() idea looks promising; thanks.

Comment: @SomeNoobStudent It can look like https://pastebin.com/Bw0qSV8t, but it depends on your specific situation you have in your case. You might want to add a MCVE to show the system/requirements/restrictions you have.